# How do I add a parent to a commit in git?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

I recently rebranched - that is, created a new branch off `master` and merged in a feature branch, e.g. `TASK-123`, with the new branch, `TASK-123-b`, replacing the feature branch that was merged into it. This is a regular action in our git workflow whenever a feature branch conflicts with `master`.

When I merged `TASK-123` into `TASK-123-b`, there was of course a merge conflict, which I've resolved and then committed. The new branch, `TASK-123-b`, and the commit merging in `TASK-123`, only have one parent: `master`

How can I modify the commit so that both `master` and `TASK-123` are its parents? I assume `git rebase` will be involved, but beyond that I don't know how to add a parent branch/commit to a commit.

My commit history currently looks like this:

```
    master -*---*-----* ...
             \         \
  TASK-123    *---*-*   \
                         \   
TASK-123-b                * ...
```

I want my commit history to look like this:

```
    master -*---*-----* ...
             \         \
  TASK-123    *---*-*   \
                     \   \   
TASK-123-b            \---* ...
```

Note: I haven't pushed `TASK-123-b` to a remote yet, so rebasing commits on it should cause no problems with my coworkers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redo the merge of TASK-123 into TASK-123-b because it looks like it didn't work like you wanted it to. To do that, find the commit hash in TASK-123-b just before the merge and reset your branch pointer there:

```
$ git checkout -B TASK-123-b abc123
```

Then repeat the merge:

```
$ git merge TASK-123
```

If you reset the branch pointer, the old merge commit is going to be orphaned and won't show up in the logs unless you specifically mention it as an argument. If you want to get it back, the hash will be recorded in the reflog or you could just copy the hash down somewhere and use the `checkout -B` command to put it back if you decide you need to.

If you don't want to resolve the conflict again, then don't reset the branch pointer, just merge again:

```
$ git checkout TASK-123-b
$ git merge TASK-123
```

And remove the old branch:

```
$ git branch -d TASK-123
```

Comment: The first part of your answer worked for me. Turns out I had somehow told git I was no longer trying to merge while I was working on resolving the conflicts. When I re-did it, I got it right. Out of curiousity, is there a way to give a commit arbitrary parent commits/branches?

Comment: @MartinCarney: if you use the low level `git commit-tree` command you can make a commit with whatever parents you like (they come from your `-p` arguments).  You then have to manually reference the new commit, though.  A stopped (e.g., conflicted) merge leaves a file `MERGE_HEAD` containing the ID of the to-be-merged-in commit and `git commit` will make the next commit with `HEAD` as first-parent and whatever is in `MERGE_HEAD` as second-parent.  It sounds like somehow you lost the `MERGE_HEAD` file.

Comment: You could manually write a commit object: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#Commit-Objects
Or you could checkout the thing you want to be the first parent, and then run merge like this: `git merge parent-2 parent-3 ... parent-n` and then fix all of the merge conflicts with `checkout --ours`. I think that would work.

Comment: @torek Does that mean if I create a `MERGE_HEAD` file with the commit hash of the second parent, then commit, git will count the commit as a merge of `HEAD` and `MERGE_HEAD` regardless of what's actually in the commit?

Comment: @MartinCarney: yes, although that's not documented anywhere (so it might potentially change—which is not really that different from the case if it *were* documented, really :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

For explanation purpose, assume that your commits are identified like this:

```
    master -a---c-----f-----h ...
             \         \
  TASK-123    b---d-e   \
                         \   
TASK-123-b                g---i ...
```

---

#### TL;DR

1. Rebase, remove the merge commit (commit `g`), and edit the commit before the merge (commit `f`).
2. Instead of doing `git commit --amend` on `f`, do a `git merge e --no-commit`.
3. Checkout all files from commit `g` using `git checkout g -- .`.
4. Commit and continue the rebasing process.

---

#### Detailed Answer

If your commit tree can be represented like this:

**First**, rebase using the commit hash second before the merge commit (the merge commit is `g`, so the commit hash will be used is the `<commit-c-sha>`)

```
$ git rebase --interactive <commit-c-sha>
```

This will generate a todo list like this:

```
pick <commit-f-sha>  <commit-f-message>   -----> change this to edit
pick <commit-g-sha>  <commit-g-message>   -----> remove this line
pick <commit-i-sha>  <commit-i-message>
...
```

So your todo list will be like:

```
edit <commit-f-sha>  <commit-f-message>
pick <commit-i-sha>  <commit-i-message>
...
```

**Second**, create a merge with no commit.

```
$ git merge <commit-e-sha> --no-commit
```

Here, we don't want to actually *edit* the commit `f`. Instead, we prepare a commit for commit `g` replacement.

This gives us a merge commit format and the flexibility to do some works on the merge commit (such as: modify files, modify commit properties, etc).

**Third**, we checked out all files from commit `g` to current index without moving the `HEAD`.

```
$ git checkout <commit-g-sha> -- .
```

This makes sure that the files will be committed are all the same with the files in commit `g`.

**Fourth**, persist the change and continue the rebasing process. For example:

```
$ git commit
$ git rebase --continue
```

You can add any commit options (but don't add `--amend`) or replace it with `git commit-tree` command.

After this, commit `g` will have two parents and all of the commits after `g` are following as well.

```
    master -a---c-----f-----h ...
             \         \
  TASK-123    b---d-e   \
                     \   \   
TASK-123-b            \---g---i ... and all of the following commits
```

---

#### Notes 1: Specify timestamp

When you make a commit, git by default set the commit date using the current time. If you want to specify the timestamp, you can check on `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` & `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` variables and the `--date`  option

ref: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_date_formats

---

#### Notes 2: Commit-Tree (not tried yet)

If you want a more flexible way to specify the commit parent(s), you can do a `checkout` and create the commit using the [`commit-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree) command instead of the `merge` -> `checkout` -> `commit` pattern.